# Match an XSLT Regex Pattern

Tags: regex, xslt

I've the below XML String

```
<para><content-style font-style="bold">59/App/1/1 Amendment—</content-style>
</para>
```

and the below regex match.

```
 <xsl:template match="para[fn:not(@align)]/content-style[1]/text()">
    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="fn:not(contains(substring-before(.,'/'),' '))">

 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <span class="phrase">
                    <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3),regex-group(4))}"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                </span>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>                

        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <span class="phrase">
                    <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3))}"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                </span>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <span class="phrase">
                            <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2))}"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                        </span>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
       </xsl:non-matching-substring>
       </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>                  
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

here i want to match `59/App/1/1` with regex, but i'm unable to understand how to do it. 
I tried to `analyze-string` using `<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)/([0-9]+[\w+]?)">` , and it is not getting matched., please let me know where i went wrong and how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern:

```
([0-9]+[\w+]?)
```

- `[0-9]+` matches a single character present in the range between 0 and 9, as many times as possible
- `[\w+]?` matches a single character from `+` and `[A-Za-z0-9_]` character set, zero and one time.

Since this pattern will never match the word `App`; your regex fails.

You can use the following pattern:

```
(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)
```

as `\w` already includes the `[0-9]` class.

Comment: Note that with the regular expression language used in XSLT/XPath 2.0 and later the `\w` character class contains all Unicode word characters which is much more than the ASCII characters a-z, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs which defines `\w` as `[#x0000-#x10FFFF]-[\p{P}\p{Z}\p{C}]` which is `all characters except the set of "punctuation", "separator" and "other" characters`.

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92 and Martin for the answers, this works like a charm,  here I've a small doubt by using `\w+`, can we do a number formatting?